# Poor Wireless Connection Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Ralink

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless, wifi

My connection to the internet when connecting via wireless is very unstable and slow (down to 5-10 bytes/sec at times) and connections are frequently dropped. I am using WICD and am connecting via an external USB wireless card (WLAN2). This issue is isolated to Ubuntu, since the same rig in the same position connecting to the same AP when booted into Yosemite works beautifully. I suspect it is a driver issue, but have tried many fixes suggested by other posts and none have made any difference. Here are the outputs of ifconfig, iwconfig and lshw:

```
benjamintrapani@benjamintrapani-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 94:de:80:b1:19:00  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

ham0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7a:79:19:10:6a:23  
      inet addr:25.16.106.35  Bcast:25.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::7879:19ff:fe10:6a23/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2620:9b::1910:6a23/96 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1404  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:64 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:13700 (13.7 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:1152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:132871 (132.8 KB)  TX bytes:132871 (132.8 KB)

wlan2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7c:dd:90:82:2e:72  
      inet addr:10.0.0.10  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::7edd:90ff:fe82:2e72/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2601:6:7580:e5e:94f5:8bb3:4446:bf19/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2601:6:7580:e5e:7edd:90ff:fe82:2e72/64 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:25806 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:24509 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:25435219 (25.4 MB)  TX bytes:14042934 (14.0 MB)


benjamintrapani@benjamintrapani-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ iwconfig

 eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off

wlan2     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"HOME-86D2"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 90:1A:CA:AC:86:D0   
      Bit Rate=78 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=65/70  Signal level=-45 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:1063  Invalid misc:34   Missed beacon:0

ham0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

benjamintrapani@benjamintrapani-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ sudo lshw -C network

```
*-network DISABLED      
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RT5392 PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 00
   serial: 00:e0:5c:00:04:93
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.16.0-37-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:16 memory:f7d00000-f7d0ffff
 *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 06
   serial: 94:de:80:b1:19:00
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:42 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
 *-network:0
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 2
   bus info: usb@1:1.1
   logical name: wlan2
   serial: 7c:dd:90:82:2e:72
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=3.16.0-37-generic firmware=0.29 ip=10.0.0.10 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
  *-network:1
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 3
   logical name: ham0
   serial: 7a:79:19:10:6a:23
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full ip=25.16.106.35 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

Comment: It says "Tx excessive retries:1063" and "Power Management:off". Could Tx be underpowered? I don't know if "Tx-Power=20 dBm" is normal or high or low.

Comment: did you try other drivers? I had a similar problem and I recall the problem was a driver problem. Maybe even downgraded.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on askubuntu.com

Comment: Can you post the exact adapter model? Ralink has some windows and linux driver issues and this can help isolate what your problem actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who contributed, turns out it was a driver issue and updating the drivers to the latest proprietary versions fixed the issues.